# Column Definition in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, model

How do i set default value in hibernate field?

```
    @Column(name="status",nullable=false,columnDefinition="int default 1")
    private Integer status;
```

The above code doesn't works in my entity class.

Please Help me

**Edit**

```
public class Base {

    @Column(name ="status")
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private Integer status;
}

public class myclass extends Base
{

private string name;

}
```

Comment: What is your database server product?

Comment: @CanB MySQL5.6 server

Comment: Have you tried to delete and recreate the table? Maybe that could help.

Comment: I tried many times, but not working

Comment: Can you post more code in detail

Comment: @jicks Ok, now I've done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use @MappedSuperclass above the base and try it.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Base {

    @Column(name ="status")
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private Integer status;
}

public class myclass extends Base
{

private string name;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Initialize status property with value 1

```
private Integer status = 1;
```

Comment: This is used for java code, but I need in ColumnDefinition